# How do I call a batch file from an MSI

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer

I have an msi installer that needs to call a few batch files to finish the install procedure. The batch file copies extra files from the installer to a few directories and then modifies permissions on several of those directories. We want to continue using the batch files because there is not a lot of time left in our development schedule. I am not using WIX.

If possible I would like to capture the output of the batch as it goes and write it to a log file.

Found bellow is the code I am using to try to run the batch file from a custom action. It opens a cmd window, runs for a while but never seems to finish. If I run the same batch files directly from the command prompt they work.

```
//Set the environment to the directory containing the bat files

ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(batch);
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(argument))
   info.Arguments = argument;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = info;
process.Start();

// Capture the standard error and standard output
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Turns out the issue I was having was a part of the logging process. If there were no log messages written the reading process would block the installer. This was clearly bad and made my life sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll need to create a custom action.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998703/run-batch-file-in-windows-installer-commit).

Comment: I guess I just have to work harder to get it working. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Many anti-virus programs may stop execution of .BAT files during an installation process, you should really be doing this using standard Windows Installer functionality or as a C++ Custom Action