# How do we include a batch file in a msi installer which should run every time the msi is installed?

Tags: c#-3.0, windows-installer

Wow do we include a batch file in a msi installer which should run every time the msi is installed?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998703/run-batch-file-in-windows-installer-commit

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it might work if you create a custom action to execute `cmd.exe` and have the path and name of the batch file as a parameter.
Otherwise you can create a custom action that contains a vbscript file that executes the .bat file (or possibly you can use a vbscript instead of a bat file).

Just be aware that I've heard that some antivirus programs can get a bit nervous if you include scripts in your msi and might make the install fail.

Comment: Regarding scripts in custom actions, indeed, MS employee (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx) says he does not recommend using scripts in custom actions.