# Uninstalling through Add/Remove doesn't delete the files, registry keys, or services it's supposed to

Tags: windows, cmd, uninstallation, windows-installer

So I've been trying to understand how Windows Installer works exactly trying to solve this problem. As it stands I go to Add/Remove programs and remove the software.
 This I guess calls`msiexec.exe /x {product id}`and removes the software. The problem is the only thing it really removes is the desktop icon and a couple files and I think one registry key.

I've since been trying to understand what exactly `msiexec.exe /x` does when it is called. I think it goes through the `InstallExecuteSequence` table in the `.msi` file and runs all of the actions? I'm really not 100% sure. I see, looking inside the `.msi` file, that there is a `RemoveFile` and`RemoveRegistry` table and also a DeleteService Action, but I just don't get how it all fits together and why it isn't removing everything it puts in when I install the software.

The end goal here is to uninstall the services, delete the registry keys, and delete the root folder that is created in program files. Can anyone provide any insight?

Comment: I solved this by creating custom actions that called .bat files to remove everything. If you need help you can look at this response for what to do:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/998756/1427105

Answer (score 0):

Remove file etc are for upgrading to a new version.
Ie old version had a file old.dat, new one has new.dat, so you tell msi to delete old.dat, to tidy up.

Have you tested to see what happens on a clean machine, because my instant suspicion would be registry / installer database being messed up if I got this sort of behaviour.

Comment: It has the same outcome on every machine and it is possible that the installer database is messed up. I'm just not sure where to look to determine the issue with this. Really the only resource I have to fix this problem is being able to edit the .msi file. If there is something else I would have to edit or deal with I would need to make arrangements to do so.

Comment: Totally clean machine, if it installs sucessfully but won't uninstall, got to be the msi itself

Answer (score 0):

Because your end goal is to uninstall the service/software you can use the following commando(run it from a "cmd"-shell):

```
    wmic product where name="product name" call uninstall
```

To see more examples/documentation of the wmic command: [goto here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2947/windows_uninstall_application_command_line/)

Comment: Sorry I should have added that this is my end goal through the Add/Remove Program. I can get everything uninstalled just fine, but now I have to do it through Add/Remove which, like I mentioned, calls msiexec.exe /x {product code}, so there's not really a work around. The InstallExecuteSequence that I'm dealing with looks similar to the one at [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372038(v=vs.85).aspx) Am I correct in saying that when you uninstall the software it runs through this sequence table again? I don't really see anything else it could be doing.