# Outlook 2010 Add In - How do I force outlook to close before installing

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I have developed an add-in for Outlook 2010 in c#, and I have discovered that if outlook is open when you install the add-in, it doesn't display my ribbon at the top.

I want to know, how can I either force outlook to close before installation takes place, or show a popup message to tell the user they must close outlook before they can proceed??

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you available to add a Batch File to your installation package?

Comment: Can you elaborate?? how do I do that??

Comment: ok.. I have created a batch file that will close outlook.. but how to I add that to my installation package?

Comment: damn, I hadn't seen your comment.. I just post that as an answer

Comment: thanks BrOSs - I have got the batch file all sorted, im just not sure how to get it into my install package??  To publish I am right-clicking on my project in VS2010 and clicking publish.  Is there somewhere in the project properties that I can add this batch file??

Answer (score 0):

This is a **workaround** solution:

Open a Notepad, add the following line:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM outlook.exe /T
```

And save the file as:

> AnyName.bat

In your installation package, make sure that *"AnyName.bat"* file runs first.

Regards

Comment: please, take a look at [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998703/run-batch-file-in-windows-installer-commit) question.