# Wix - How do I launch another MSI (or EXE) inside my installer? (C#)

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I need to run another installer that is a requirement to be able to run my application. How would I launch the other installer, or provide an option to inside of my Wix Installer?

Comment: You need to create a [Custom Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998703/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that other installer is a prerequisite then normal practice is to install it via the Burn bootstrapper, installing prerequisites and then your MSI product. There are a number of reasons why this is better, the main one perhaps that you cannot safely install an MSI-based setup from your MSI (because recursive MSI installs don't work).

If it is a prerequisite then it wouldn't be optional, so perhaps more detail is needed.

If you just need to run a program from your setup then look at custom actions. Without a more detailed description it's hard to say where or when would be the best implementaion.