# How to run a “.bat” file in setup and Deployment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am newbie creating a setup in visual studio 2010 in which I want to run my example.bat file in which there are two file, one example.exe file and one example2.msi file, I want to run example.bat files now my project creates a shortcut on desktop which run example.bat file.
i want when user run the set up so example.bat file should run.
How to run first batch file in my setup and deployment project?

Answer (score 0):

Bundle the .bat file with your setup project and call it in the Custom Action. Custom Actions allows you to specify additional actions to be performed on the target computer at the end of an installation. Please refer the following links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28VS.80%29.aspx

[Executing a script file from a Windows Installer Custom Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98778/executing-a-script-file-from-a-windows-installer-custom-action)